# Swift give let values

Tags: arrays, swift, let

I want to write dont let values

I have

```
 "id": 17,
 "name": "",
    "team_id": 4,
    "is_delete": false,
    "created_at": "2018-04-30",
    "members": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "username": "ie",
        }
    ],
    "description": null,
```

Im try to do this

```
let id: Int
let name: String
let team_id: Int
let is_delete: Bool
let created_at: String

let description: NSNull
```

but dont know hove correctly add the members array . and NSNull is correct to null value?

Comment: Members is a dictionary

Comment: @Jake No, it's an array of dictionary.

Comment: Yea I was editing that and you beat me to the punch. Slower on the app than on my Mac.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Are you trying to create a struct that can be mapped back and forth to JSON? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I suppose you are trying to write a `Codable` struct/class that can be used to decode your JSON?

The way to handle `null` is to use optional types. From the name, I guess `description` would have been a string if it were not null, so we should use `String?` as the type:

```
struct TeamMember: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let username: String
}

struct Team: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let team_id: Int
    let is_delete: Bool
    let created_at: String
    let members: [TeamMember]

    let description: String? // <---- this line
}
```

Here is an example of decoding:

```
// I escaped the json using an online decoder I found. It's basically the same JSON in the question.
let jsonData = "{ \"id\": 17,\r\n \"name\": \"\",\r\n    \"team_id\": 4,\r\n    \"is_delete\": false,\r\n    \"created_at\": \"2018-04-30\",\r\n    \"members\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"id\": 42,\r\n            \"username\": \"ie\",\r\n        }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"description\": null}".data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let team = try! decoder.decode(Team.self, from: jsonData!)
print(team.id)
```

Comment: Just came here to suggest structures. Great answer!